# How does ${n^2 - 9n = 0}$ turn into ${n(n - 9) = 0}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

> $${n^2 - 9n = 0}$$
>   How does that turn into ${n(n - 9) = 0}$?
>
> Can someone, please, explain the logic behind this?

This arose in a problem involving the number of diagonals in a particular polygon:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{n(n - 3)}{2} = 3n &\quad\to\quad n^2 - 3n = 6n \\
&\quad\to\quad n^2 - 9n = 0 \\[4pt]
&\quad\to\quad n(n - 9) = 0 \\[4pt]
&\quad\to\quad n = 0, 9
\end{align}$$

The problem is easy to solve. I just don't get how $n^2−9n=0$ expands to $n(n−9)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is verified by the distributive law. It is carried through originally by remembering the distributive law.

Answer (score 3):

Choose one vertex, $n$ choices, choose another one from the remaining ones which is not adjacent or equal, $n-3$ this gives $n^2-3n$. Now since you can do it in any order, you divide by $2$ to account for double counting giving

> $$\#d = {1\over 2}n(n-3).$$

Not sure how you got the $9$. Clearly that's negative for a square, but there are $2$ diagonals for a square. Also not sure why you have the $=0$, are you sure this is how the problem was posed?

Comment: @W.Zlacki well if that's all, just note that $n(n-9) = n\cdot n -n\cdot 9$ by the distributive property, so $n(n-9)=n^2-9n$ is the same way of saying this without so many multiplication symbols.

Comment: You actually end up double counting the diagonals, so the final formula is $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$

Comment: I felt his answer was more suited to what I was looking for.

Comment: d=1n!!!!!!!!!!!